# Migrating from createContainer to withTracker in Meteor / React

Tags: reactjs, meteor

Meteor / React newb here and I'm having a problem upgrading from `createContainer` (which is depreciated) to `withTracker` in the following.

```
export default createContainer(() => {
  Meteor.subscribe('users', PER_PAGE);

  return { users: Users.find({}).fetch() };
}, UsersList);
```

I've tried the following...

```
import { withTracker } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';

.....

export default withTracker(() => {
  Meteor.subscribe('users', PER_PAGE);

  return { users: Users.find({}).fetch() };
}, UsersList);
```

but I'm getting errors in the console :

```
Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.
```

Could somebody show me where I'm going wrong please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a syntax error in the last line of your code snippet

```
export default withTracker(() => {
  Meteor.subscribe('users', PER_PAGE);

  return { users: Users.find({}).fetch() };
}, UsersList);
```

Replace it with

```
export default withTracker(() => {
  Meteor.subscribe('users', PER_PAGE);

  return { users: Users.find({}).fetch() };
})(UsersList);
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I literally just swapped out `createContainer` for `withTracker`. Didn't realise the end of the function had to be declared slightly differently.